# Very slow Reflection (trying to write a generic wrapper)

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to write a generic method to wrap an SDK we're using. The SDK provides "AFElement" objects that represent our data object, and each data AFElement has a collection of "AFAttributes" that map to our data objects' properties.

I've created a generic method which uses reflection to check the object it's called for's properties and get them (if they exist) from the `AFElement.Attributes`:

```
private T ConvertAFElementTo<T>(AFElement element, T item) where T : class, new()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        //Get the Attribute object that represents this property
        AFAttribute attribrute = element.Attributes[property.Name];
        if (attribrute != null)
        {
            //check if we have the same type
            if (property.PropertyType.Equals(attribrute.Type))
            {
                //set our property value to that of the attribute
                var v = attribrute.GetValue().Value;
                property.SetValue(item, v);
            }
            //check if we have an AFElement as an Attribute that will need converting to a data object
            else if (attribrute.Type.Equals(typeof(AFElement)))
            {
                AFElement attributeElement = attribrute.GetValue().Value as AFElement;
                Type attributeType = null;

                //look up it's data type from the template
                TypeConversionDictionary.TryGetValue(attributeElement.Template, out attributeType);

                if (attributeType != null)
                {
                    //set it as a .NET object
                    property.SetValue(item, ConvertAFElementTo(attributeElement, Activator.CreateInstance(attributeType)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

The idea is I can throw any of my data objects T at this method and it would populate them, and it works, except it's exceptionally slow.

It takes around 10 seconds to get 63 objects (11 properties each, all simple types like Guid, String and Single), 93% of the time is in this conversion method. I've heard reflection wasn't very efficient, but is is this inefficient?

Is there any other way I could do this, or a way to speed things up? Am I being stupid even trying to do something this generic?

Comment: 10 seconds for 63 objects sounds like a huge time, but it's very hard to tell what's actually going on without knowing more about it. If each object has 1000 properties, for example, it doesn't sound quite as unrealistic. A [mcve] would be helpful...

Comment: Sorry, should have explained. They have 11 properties, all simple types like Guid, String and Single. I started making an example, but not sure if there's much point as the SDK is something that's propriety.

Comment: @Joe that doesn't sound like right... 63 objects with 11 properties in 10 seconds is WAY too slow. Reflection is not fast, but it's not **that** slow (I've used it to read/write properties, even non-cached, in thousands of objects with more than 10 scalar properties in way less than 10 seconds). Are you sure the performance problem is caused by the function you have shown here? At first glance, it doesn't look like it should be **that** slow. Have you measured the performance of this method?

Comment: I suspected so. I created a Mapping class to pre-map the properties. To confirm, I removed all reflection from the method and did the mapping in the initialization. The method was still taking ages, so the problem wasn't reflection. The actual issue was that the SDK I'm using was lazy-loading the data when accessed (so the delay was "hidden" in my translation method), and was performing lots of trips for it - I needed to force it to load before hand.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule when you do reflection is not to do any lookup operation etc. at execution time, but only once during an initialization step.

In your example, you could have a class for that method that would do the reflection lookup in the static constructor - ONCE when the class is first accessed. All method calls then will use the already evaluated reflection elements.

Reflection has to do a lot - and you really make it a lot harder by being fully dynamic.

I suggest you do more profiling and find out which methods exactly are slow ;) THen try to do the reflection part a little less often.

You can have an AFAMapper class that gets initialized for every pair of Source and Target ;)

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. I've now created a Mapping class, and for testing I removed all reflection from the method and did it in the initialization. The method was still taking ages, so the problem wasn't reflection. The actual issue was that the SDK I'm using was lazy-loading the data when accessed (so the delay was "hidden" in my translation method), and was performing lots of trips for it - I needed to force it to load before hand.